# Why doesn't this code attach an image to MMS message?

Tags: android, android-intent, mms

The code is pretty basic

```
share_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Uri image = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mypac.app/" +
                        imageToSend);
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/jpeg");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, image);

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share with"));
            }
        });
```

The variable `imageToSend` is `int` - ID of the image in /drawables directory.

In the share dialog, I can see the Messaging as option. I choose it but no image is attached. There is a message "an image cannot be attached". If I manually add image from the sdcard, then it's being attached to the MMS message with no problems.

What may be the problem with the code above?

**EDIT**

Tried the other solution: attach image from SD. This is the code.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "img.png");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share with"));
```

This does NOT work as well. I still get message that the file cannot be attached. And again Facebook app works flawlessly.

Comment: Have you tried attaching an image from the SD programatically, rather than trying to attach a private image from your resources.

Comment: I cannot do that as images I want to attach are part of the project (they are located in /drawables directory). Have you tried compiling this code and attaching an image to MMS message via share dialog? If you have a better code, would you mind sharing it?

Comment: Now you started an itch :). I MAY grab the image and save it on sd before attaching it, but this will cause the app to be sooooo slow due to image stream being written on the SD. However, this is illogical solution for such trivial task. I must be making a mistake somewhere...

Comment: All I'm saying is if you try that and it works it would mean the problem is the file path of the image

Comment: It seems it's not. Look at the EDIT part. :(

Comment: It was an issue with public folders. Those who want to implement this have to save the image first into some public folder on the SD (`File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`), and then share it with other apps.

Comment: Thanks. I just wished you shared some code with me ;). Anyhow, the problem is solved and the solution is here for other developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intent is transfered to an external application.

The android:resource scheme is only valid locally.

That means that you have to copy the image from your resources to an external directory and link this new file in your Intent

Comment: or actually any directory large enough to hold the image and public enough to be accessed by the MMS application. so yeah, basically the SD card is a good choice (but not the only one)

Comment: Well, the Facebook app works? And Messaging does not? If I choose to publish image, FB app uploads it and publishes it?

Comment: do you mean that this code opens a chooser that offers facebook or mms, and that only facebook actually works?

Comment: Yes it does. FB loads the message, while Messaging does not. Try it yourself :). BTW Peter's code is better than mine. It's more programmatic.

Comment: it would be even better to use an Uri builder, but that is not really the problem, is it? do you have a stacktrace for the crash in the mms app?

Comment: No. That's why I am confused. Neither debugger nor Logcat catches it.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag from the Intent class : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION

As the name says, this should transfer Read permission on the given Uri to the activity started by that intent.

Answer (score 0):

What does your Uri.parse() return? Null maybe?

Try this:

```
Resources resources = context.getResources(); 
Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + 
resources.getResourcePackageName(imageToSend) + '/' + 
resources.getResourceTypeName(imageToSend) + '/' + 
resources.getResourceEntryName(imageToSend) );
```

Comment: Hm, this works when I look it via debugger, but when I choose Messaging it crashes with error "The application Messaging (process com.android.mms) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." I think this is the same message I got. When the right image is passed, it crashes. When no image is passed, it opens with message that the image cannot be attached. Any suggestions?