# Sharing an Image in app's data directory through a ContentProvider on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to expose a .png file located in my application's /data directory through a ContentProvider but instead of reaching the `openFile` method `query` is being called. Now I only ever have a single image which I need to expose for sharing to other applications, how can I setup my Intent to goto `openFile` instead of `query`?

```
Intent shareImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            shareImageIntent.setType("image/*");

            shareImageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareImageIntent, "Share image"));
```

Where the Uri looks like

```
content://my.package.contentprovider/fileName
```

Or alternatively do I need to create a database for this and return a cursor?

UPDATE

So this appears to be working on everything except the SMS app (which is what I decided to test first) I would like to support sharing to it however.

Here's the relevant stack trace:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Query on
>   content://mypackage.myprovider/someImage.png returns null result. at
>   com.android.mms.ui.UriImage.initFromContentUri(UriImage.java:104) at
>   com.android.mms.ui.UriImage.(UriImage.java:63) at
>   com.android.mms.model.ImageModel.initModelFromUri(ImageModel.java:83)
>   at com.android.mms.model.ImageModel.(ImageModel.java:65) at
>   com.android.mms.data.WorkingMessage.changeMedia(WorkingMessage.java:481)
>   at
>   com.android.mms.data.WorkingMessage.setAttachment(WorkingMessage.java:375)
>   ...

So the SMS app is performing a query instead of reading directly from `openFile`, which every other app on my phone seems to do (including other Google apps)

Does anyone know what I need to return here to fullfil the query appropriately? I'm going to go AOSP digging now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging through the source code of the SMS (MMS really) app this is what I came up with.

Inside `UriImage.initFromContentUri` the application makes the query code and assumes there are 2 returned columns in the `Cursor`

```
 } else {
   filePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Images.Media.DATA));
   mContentType = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE));
 }
```

So inorder for your `ContentProvider` to work with the MMS app, you need to return a `Cursor` in  `query` that only has one row and the two columns (Images.Media.DATA & Images.Media.MIME_TYPE) with the appropriate data. The MMS will then make the call to `openFile` to actually retrieve the image.

Comment: Also note that the columns are not requested but need to be filled for the sms app.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to share a image resource is to save it to external storage (SD-card) and then do:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(pathToFile);
```

**Update:**

Try using

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.package.yourapp/" +imageResID);
```

**Update2**

Try saving file to Media Store and then sending it:

```
String url = Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), imageFile.getName(), imageFile.getName());

Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(url);
```

**Final Update** using `ContentProvider` and `Cursor`:

Your `ContentProvider` must implement `query(..)` method and it must return a `Cursor`. See the [source code of `UrlImage.initFromContentUri(..)`](http://www.google.com/codesearch#dpDz7Q08o9c/src/com/android/mms/ui/UriImage.java&type=cs&l=103) (which is internally used by MMS app) to see how cursor is called. Take a look at the [`MatrixCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) if it fits the bill.

Comment: Im specifically trying to access my Internal memory. I'm using the external by default but if its not available I need a fallback.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175498/why-doesnt-this-code-attach-an-image-to-mms-message

Comment: What if the user doesn't have a sdcard? Weird but possible.

Comment: @Francisco thats what I'm trying to address (not just an SD but external storage). @ Peter That question is dealing with things in the Resources of the application, my Image is created dynamically then saved to my local directory.

Comment: Yeah, true. Try the workaround via saving file to media store.

Comment: @Peter take a look at my update please, what I'm doing seems to be working for everything except the SMS app.

Answer (score 0):

If your content provider is already working you can access to a ParcelFileDescriptor via the method [openFileDescriptor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openFileDescriptor%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29) in the content provider.

A quick, and dirty, example for this:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor = mContext.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(IMGURI, "r");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
```

Cheers!

Comment: Yes my ContentResolver is working fine, the issue is that the SMS app is not using it correctly. Please see my update.